# Getting "private method `require' called for :params:Symbol" when trying to save my object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, parameters

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this in my controller …

```
  def create
    @myobject = MyObject.new(MyObject_params(:params))
    @current_user = User.find(session["user_id"])
    @myobject.user = @current_user
    if @myobject.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to controller: "users", action: "index", notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
      end
    else
      format.html { render action: "index" }
    end
  end

  private

    def MyObject_params(params) 
      # Main Code goes here
      params.require(:myobject).permit(:time_in_ms, :name)
      params[:myobject][:time_in_ms] = (params[:myobject][:hour].to_i * 60 * 60 + params[:myobject][:minute].to_i * 60 + params[:myobject][:second].to_i) * 1000
    end
```

but when I submit my form, I get the error

```
private method `require' called for :params:Symbol
```

on this line, “params.require(:myobject).permit(:time_in_ms, :name, :distance, :distance_units)”.  Not sure what I’m missing (or I have accidentally included).  Thanks for help, - Dave

**Edit:**

After trying the suggestion given, I get the error

```
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

on the line

```
@myobject = MyObject.new(MyObject_params)
```

In addition to making the adjustment in the suggestion, I also changed the method signature, "def MyObject_params(params)" to "def MyObject_params."

Comment: This error is due to params is not a object it is a symbol

Comment: Check it out what you get in the params

Comment: Also MyObject_params shouldn't be capitalized in the method call to require.  Change it to   "def myobject_params(params)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since others answers are correct. I leave you the code I think must work.

```
def create
  @myobject = MyObject.new(myobject_params)
  @current_user = User.find(session["user_id"])
  @myobject.user = @current_user
  if @myobject.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to controller: "users", action: "index", notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
    end
  else
    format.html { render action: "index" }
  end
end

private

  def myobject_params
    # Main Code goes here
    params[:myobject][:time_in_ms] = (params[:myobject][:hour].to_i * 60 * 60 + params[:myobject][:minute].to_i * 60 + params[:myobject][:second].to_i) * 1000
    params.require(:myobject).permit(:time_in_ms, :name)
  end
```

Summary of changes:

1. Remove parameters from the method `myobject_params` on it's call and definition (also I changed to snake_case as it is expected in Ruby).
2. Since `time_in_ms` was converted from `hour`, `minute` and `second` you must permit parameters after they were called for use.
3. The return from `myobject_param`, after reorder will be a hash.

And this should remove the 2 errors you reported.

Comment: I used your code and I'm not getting the error anymore.  I'm getting a different error but I don't think it has anything to do with you.  I'm going to investigaet that and then I'll come back and accept.

Comment: I guess the point 3 is no longer necessary after I changed the order inside of `myobject_params` method.

Answer (score 6):

As Brad Werth stated you are trying to pass :params into your MyObject_params method.  Since you have marked this method as private in your controller, it will refuse to accept an explicit receiver!  There is a wealth of information on private vs public vs protected ruby methods but the long short of it is that you can not call any private method directly on an object (such as `@user.make_admin`) .  This protects you from outside sources trying to manipulate the use of certain methods.

Changing `@myobject = MyObject.new(MyObject_params(:params))` to

```
 @myobject = MyObject.new(MyObject_params)
```

is what you want.  I would also recommend following Ruby best practices and downcasing your MyObject_params method to `my_object_params`

Comment: I updated my question with the output of trying your sugestion.  Basically, changing the line to what you suggest gives me the error, "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.".

Comment: You'll have to add an argument to your method if you kept it the same.  It should be  " @myobject = Myobject.new(my_object_params(params))  "  however normally in rails when dealing with parameters your private method will not also accept an argument. and be listed as "@myobject = Myobject.new(my_object_params)   "

Comment: Can you spell it out for me in code because I'm still getting errors.  When I try your suggestion about adding the params, making the line "@my_object = MyObject.new(MyObject_params(params))" (and forcing me to add a "params" argument in my private method), I get the error "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument" on the "my_object = MyObject.new(MyObject_params(params))" line.

Answer (score 5):

The error message you have is telling you that you are trying to call a private method on a symbol. When you are doing this: `@myobject = MyObject.new(MyObject_params(:params))`, you are passing the symbol `:params` to the method. It looks like you really want the params hash, which would be `@myobject = MyObject.new(MyObject_params(params))` (not a symbol).

As both methods have the same scope, you may consider not passing the params as an argument at all, but rather just refer to it in the `MyObject_params` method the same as you would in the `create` method. Also consider adjusting `MyObject_params` to at least `my_object_params`, to fit Ruby conventions, if not something more descriptive.